# Call fields on my form

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, filter, servlet-filters

I'm using Java Web Applications, I have a login(index) with filter:

Filter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (debug) {
        log("Filtro:doFilter()");
    }

    doBeforeProcessing(request, response);

    Throwable problem = null;
    try {
              String usr = request.getParameter("usuario");
        String pswd = request.getParameter("password");
        if(usr == null && pswd == null){
             request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html").forward(request, response);
        }

        if(usr.equals("Cliente") && pswd.equals("123") ){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/Cliente.jsp").forward(request, response);
       }else if (usr.equals("Supervisor") && pswd.equals("123")){ 
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/Supervisor.jsp").forward(request, response);
       }else if(usr.equals("Caja") && pswd.equals("123")){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/Caja.jsp").forward(request, response);
       }else request.getRequestDispatcher("/unautorized.jsp").forward(request, response);


        chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

So when I logged as a Client, it redirects me to login View where I have select tag:

```
 <form method="POST">

  <select name="service">
        <option value="">Select an option</option>
        <option value="value1" name="sme">param1</option>
        <option value="value2" name="sma">param2</option>
        <option value="value3" name="ac">param3</option>
        <option value="value4" name="sm">param4</option>
        <option value="value5" name="sr"> param5</option>
        <option value="value6" name="sp">param6</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

I declare variable:

```
 <%! 
    double price;
    %>
```

and finally I use Java to print some values depending of selected value on select tag:

```
 <%
    String nuevo= request.getParameter("service");
    if(nuevo != null){
    String servm = request.getParameter("service");


    if (servm.equals("sme")) {
   price = 500.00;
   out.print("Cost service: " +price);
    } else if (servm.equals("sma")) {
        price = 1200.00;
        out.print("Cost service: "+price);

    } else if (servm.equals("ac")){
        price=800.00;
    out.print("Cost service:" +price);

    }else if(nuevo.equals("sm")){
    price=50.00;
    out.print("Cost service: " +price);
    }else if(nuevo.equals("sr")){
    price=75.00;
    out.print("Cost service: " +price);
    }else if(nuevo.equals("sp")){
    price=1500.00;
    out.print("Cost service: " +price);
    }
    }
    %>
```

Servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String usr;
    String pswd;
    usr = request.getParameter("usuario");
    pswd = request.getParameter("password");
    request.getSession().setAttribute("usr", usr);
     RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Resultado.jsp");
    rd.forward(request,response);
}
```

The problem is when I clic "Send" on form button it redirects me to login(index),because I don't call user and password from filter to my form, how can I do that?
**And another problem. Is like Servlet don't works... If I delete code of doPost of servlet it just run anyway only validate my filter, so don't need it, that's normal?**
Some help please.